# JQuery plugin not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a JQuery date mask, but when I run the page it throws an error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Now, the control that this particular JQuery is meant to be working is added dynamically to a repeater control. Through this, I have looked at the ids of the control, where it was breaking and stopping in Visual Studio and what is being shown on the aspx page. The ids are identical except of the "#" that JQuery has at the start, which is not on the page.

In my JQuery code I have:

```
JQuery(function ($) {

$('#<%=date.ClientID %>').mask("99/99/9999");

});
```

Is there away to tell JQuery not to include the "#" when finding the control? I have used UniqueID but this changes any underscore into "$", which is not the same as what is on the page. My only problem is with "#" sign at the start of the ID. I have even added an alert box to check that textbox was there and it came back as null. I have tried even adding a CssClass attribute to the textbox, but this through the same error, too.

Please note that the custom user control that has the textbox is added programatically to the repeater.

Code below:

User control with repeater

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Step4.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Prototype.Step4" %>
<div style="height: 800px; margin-top: 20px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll">
    <p>
        <b>Edit Stage</b></p>

    <asp:Repeater ID="Edit" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="RowLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ControlPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Mask Control that is added dynamically to the control above

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MaskControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Prototype.CommonControls.MaskControl" %>


<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" Width="136px" CssClass="dateMask"></asp:TextBox>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//    jQuery(function ($) {
//        $('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999");
//    });
    alert(document.getElementById("MaskedDateBox"));
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried enclosing your script between CDATA?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using:

$(document).ready(function() {
$(.dateMask).mask("99/99/9999"); 
});

Adding the usercontrol dynamically won't change the css class of the added controls, where it will change the id based on it's naming container.

Comment: I have not tried what you given above, but I can on Monday, though. However, didn't you say that because I am adding the control through code behind - dynamically that the JQuery won't be able to pick the textbox id? If so, how do I apply mask without JQuery and AJAX?

Comment: @Andy5: As is said in my answer id's are tricky to catch as they are generated based on the position in the hierarchy of naming containers. You should be able to get your elements using jQuery by css class name instead of id.

Comment: Hi

Well, I applied the following code, and added some more:

$(document).ready()
{
$('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999");
});

To check that JQuery was picking up the ids of the control, I added $('input[class$=dateMask]') and sent the output to an alert box. Thankfully JQuery found the control by class, but fell over when applying the mask. So, the problem lies with the plugin! I am clean out of ideas and I don't why!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

should work.

I am not really sure what do you mean by:

> tell JQuery not to include the "#"
>   when finding the control

When you use # in a selector it means find control by id.

It is cleaner to get asp.net controls using a class selector rather than id selector, IMHO.

So to expand on the explanation a bit. If you are not using ajax then it doesn't matter how did you generate your controls - all your text boxes are present on the page when $(document).ready() event fires, and have their classes set. In that case you need to run the following code only once (that is put the js on the page and not in the control)

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999");
    jQuery('.phoneMask').mask("(999) 999-9999");  // if you have one
    ...
});
```

If you are loading the controls using ajax than you have to run the javascript code above each time ajax request completes. You can do that by registering a script with ScriptManager on in Page_Load like this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel, updatePanel.GetType(), "mask", "initMask();", true);
}
```

You'll have to define the initMask() javascript function on your page.

```
function initMask() {
    jQuery('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999");
    jQuery('.phoneMask').mask("(999) 999-9999");  // if you have one
    ...
}
```

Comment: It won't work as written because the textbox is part of a usercontrol that is dynamically loaded into the placeholder. So the 'date' won't be found ,so the client id of that control won't be rendered.

Comment: @FiveTools: What do you mean by dynamically? Ajax? You gave the same code example in your answer, except that yours has a syntax error.

Comment: Ok, is there an alternative way of applying a datemask that does not rely on JQuery or AJAX. I tried the AJAX one before the JQuery but dropped it due to other conflicts on the dynamic controls

Comment: For @FiveTools - I add the user control through my code behind based upon whatever the user entered into the application on a previous page. In other words, it could add the date control textbox, once, or any number of times.

Comment: Hi Well, I applied the following code, and added some more: $(document).ready() { $('.dateMask').mask("99/99/9999"); }); To check that JQuery was picking up the ids of the control, I added $('input[class$=dateMask]') and sent the output to an alert box. Thankfully JQuery found the control by class, but fell over when applying the mask. So, the problem lies with the plugin! I am clean out of ideas and I don't why!

Comment: jquery tip: You can use dot (.) to match elements by their class. ie. $("input.dateMask") should find all input elements with class dateMask. Note that the input element will be matched even if it has multiple classes.

Comment: quick question: are you absolutely sure that the plugin is loaded? Quick test - open up firefox, load your page. and try to run jQuery.fn.mask in firebug (or whatever js console tool you use) if the respone is not "function()" than your plugin is not loaded.

Comment: One of my colleagues has played around with it, and we think there is something wrong with the plugin itself. He has looked at the code and it is the plugin that is failing. So, we are looking at pure JS solution now